# How to test a specific argument of a mocked PHPUnit method

Tags: mocking, arguments, phpunit

My method has 3 arguments, but I just want to test the arg3, arg1 and arg2 don't matter:

```
$observer = $this->getMock('SomeObserverClass', array('myMethod'));
$observer->expects($this->once())
         ->method('myMethod')
         ->with(null, null, $this->equalTo($arg3));
```

Setting them to null or !$this->empty() does not work.

Signature of the method:

```
public function myMethod(Integer $arg1, String $arg2, String $arg3) {...}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `anything` matcher. Try:

```
$observer->expects($this->once())
     ->method('myMethod')
     ->with($this->anything(), $this->anything(), $this->equalTo($arg3));
```